# php won't execute when permission of folder set to 777

Tags: php, permissions, chmod

I am having a server with centos cpanel installed. When I execute a php code it works file. but then then I set that folder permission to 0777 it won't execute the php file and says internal server error. I tried turning off safe mode but it didn't help.

Comment: What is in the error log?

Comment: nothing at all. also the error reporting is set to E_ALL

Comment: update : it worked when i changed php handler to fcgi from suphp. how can i make it work with suphp

Comment: Not sure about that. I'd modify the question so it has that information in it.